# Running/Hosting myapp .Net Framework Web app inside Containerized IIS Server but it is pointing to Default Web site

Tags: iis, dockerfile

I am trying to build a container for .Net Framework Web application but it always pointing to default IIS website instead of myapp

```
# My Docker file

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files to the container
COPY MyApp.csproj .
COPY . .

# Restore the dependencies
RUN nuget restore

# Build the project
RUN msbuild MyApp.sln /p:Configuration=Release

# Copy Build artifacts to Output folder
COPY ./MyApp/bin/Release ./Output

# Use the IIS image to run the app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

WORKDIR /myapp

RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'; \
    New-Website -Name 'myapp' -Port 80 -PhysicalPath '/app'

# Copy the built application to the container
COPY --from=build /app/Output .
```

After running this Docker file it is creating Image and Container but when we run the container Default IIS web site is opening instead of myapp.
Any help would be appreciated.